# No solution to general Volterra integral equation of the second type?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I encountered a (likely simple) Volterra-style integral equation as part of my work. For an arbitrary function $p(s)$ which is square integrable, I have the following equation relating $p(s)$ and its integral with respect to the real-to-real function $Q$:

$$p(x) - C\int_{0}^{x}p(s)dQ(s) = 0$$

where $C$ is a known real constant.

I would hopefully like to show, without further assumptions, that this system has only the solution $p(s) = 0$. I have very little training in differential equations, so I'm a bit lost as where to begin.

Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.

Here is how you can prove this. Write the equation as
$$
p(x) = \int_0^x p(s) q(s)  ds
$$
where $q(s) = C Q'(s)$. The equation shows that $p(x)$ is differentiable, since it is equal to an antiderivative. Therefore by differentiating
$$
p'(x) = p(x) q(x) \, .
$$
and also $p(0) = \int_0^0 p(s) q(s) ds  = 0$.

To prove from this that $p(x) = 0$ for all $x$, one can use the following trick: Set $r(x) = p(x)e^{-CQ(x)}$. Then
$$r'(x) = p'(x) e^{-CQ(x)} + p(x) e^{-CQ(x)}\cdot (-CQ'(x)) = e^{-CQ(x)} \cdot \left(p'(x) - p(x) q(x) \right) = 0 
$$
So $r(x) = constant = r(0) = 0$ and therefore also $q(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Presumably this is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes (or maybe Riemann-Stieltjes) integral.  There is no indication that $Q$ is differentiable, or even continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This was very insightful.

Robert's comment is correct that this is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. However, I can add the additional assumption that Q is continuously differentiable without worry.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good point. If this is a Stieltjes integral, clearly a Calculus I level argument no longer works ... and the whole discussion could be done at a level that is higher than Calculus I.